# Excel read text file removing quotations

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read a text file into Excel that presents along the lines of:

> "DVXX = 2.37"
>
> "DVID = 1.967"
>
> "WLXX = 1906"

I created a loop that looks for specific key words, say `DVXX`, offsets and reports the value:

```
Open strFile For Input As #intFile
For i = 1 To 23
Do While Not EOF(intFile)
    Line Input #intFile, strIn
    Key_len = Len(Keywords(i))
    If Left(strIn, Key_len) = Keywords(i) Then
        strOut = Mid(strIn, Key_len + 3)
        Cells(25 + i, 1).Value = Keywords(i)
        Cells(25 + i, 2).Value = strOut
        Exit Do
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
Loop
Next i
Close #intFile
```

This code works fine when I go through and delete all of the quotations, however the text files as generated will have quotes. Is there a way of reading this information in without manually removing the quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after you read the line:

```
strIn = Replace(strIn, chr$(34), "")
```